# Pyqt4 setAlignment(Qtcore.Qt.AlignCenter) works perfectly in Linux, but not on Mac

Tags: python, linux, macos, user-interface, pyqt

For some reason, I cannot get any of my QLabels to align correctly in mac, even though the same code works perfectly in Linux.

```
def home_UI(self):
    layout = QFormLayout()
    label_image = QLabel()
    label_image.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    logo = QPixmap(logo_path)
    label_image.setPixmap(logo)
    layout.addWidget(label_image)

    disclaimer_text = "**DISCLAIMER! This application does not promise to be 100% accurate, we are not " \
                      "responsible for any losses that might occur trading " + crypto_config.CRYPTOCURRENCY + "."
    disclaimer_label = QLabel(disclaimer_text)

    instructions_text = "Application may take a few hours before building up adequet training set of an unseen cryptocurrency"
    instructions_label = QLabel(instructions_text)
    disclaimer_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    instructions_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    layout.addWidget(disclaimer_label)
    layout.addWidget(instructions_label)
    self.setTabText(0, "Home")
    self.home.setLayout(layout)
```

Here is the image centered in Linux.

[image]

And here is the same image in Mac.

[image]

Comment: Use a `QVBoxLayout` instead of a `QFormLayout`.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks a million!